# Pasar datos de una actividad a otra, no valida la Key

Tags: java, android

una consulta.

Trato de enviar datos a través de una variable de una activity a otra, pero no puedo extraer el valor.

Lo envio de esta manera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EssenMain.class);
        intent.putExtra("foto",account.getPhotoUrl());
        startActivity(intent);
```

Y lo recibo de esta manera en la otra activity:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle !=null) {
        String fotoString = bundle.getString("foto");
```

Pero se da el caso que a pesar que los datos se encuentran en el bundle, no los puedo pasar a la variable String fotoString, la misma que adquiere valor null.

Esto se valida en el modo debug, de la cual adjunto una imagen.[image: Variable aquiere valor Null a pesar de indicar la Key correcta.]

Por favor su ayuda y gracias

Comment: ¿Has depurado esto: `account.getPhotoUrl()`?  ¿Si pasas una cadena de prueba tampoco la obtienes: `intent.putExtra("foto","TEST");`. También, puedes prescindir de `Bundle` y hacer esto: `if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
//código }`... supongo que ejecutas el código en el `onCreate` de la Activity receptora.

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda. Si pasa una cadena de prueba. El tema es que si pasa también el contenido pero no puedo extraer la cadena con la dirección URL con la key correspondiente. Si tienes una idea te lo agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque el valor de `foto` se encuentra en el `bundle` y lo extraes correctamente a la variable `fotoString` ,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede deberse a dos causas,

1) Una es que tu proyecto no esta sincronizado, puedes limpiarlo y reconstruirlo con `Build` > `Clean Proyect`

2)Puede estar sucediendo que el método `load()` de `Glide` esta tomando el valor de una variable de clase que no es la que estas declarando en una linea anterior.

**Renombra la variable `fotoString` para que no tome la que tiene valor null.**

---

**Actualización:** De acuerdo a lo anterior me parece que simplemente es un tema de sincronización, por  lo tanto te sugiero detener y construir tu proyecto nuevamente.

Esta ocurriendo algo similar a esto, si no inicializo `urlPhoto` que uso en Glide (variable de color azul) esta no tendrá valor. En tu caso la variable esta dentro del `if` por lo tanto debería ser sobreescrita, construye nuevamente tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione de esta manera.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EssenMain.class);
        data = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        intent.putExtra("foto",data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

convertí el contenido a String, y lo almacene en la variable y esa si pasa sin inconveniente, no era posible hacerlo de la manera anteriormente planteada pues no había correspondencia de tipos de contenido con el tipo de variable.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle !=null) {
        String fotoString = bundle.getString("foto");
        Glide.with(this).load(fotoString).into(imageView);
    }
```

Gracias a todos y saludos

Comment: Esto es lo mismo que tienes en el código de tu pregunta, ¿cual es la diferencia?

Comment: No es lo mismo, pues si te fijas se anade la segunda linea, que toma el valor de getPhotoUrl lo pasa a String y lo almacena en la variable data, la que se envía normalmente. Saludos.